# Facebook SDK 3 crashes

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to integrate Facebook SDK3.0 in my project, but I have some crashes at the initialization part. I tried in two different ways:

- I am calling [[FBSession initWithAppId] ...], but I get GISABRT exception

> > [FBSession initWithAppID:permissions:urlSchemeSuffix:tokenCacheStrategy:]:
> >     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x22c0890 wait_fences: failed
> >     to receive reply: 10004003 2012-09-04 17:40:46.353
> >     iOSTemplate[236:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> >     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBSession
> >     initWithAppID:permissions:urlSchemeSuffix:tokenCacheStrategy:]:
> >     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x22c0890'

My code looks like:

```
    fb_session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:@"1234"  //"1234" is not my app id. I use a valid one.                       
                                            permissions:nil
                                          urlSchemeSuffix:nil 
                                       tokenCacheStrategy:nil];//k_AppId 
if(fb_session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
{ ... }
```

- I tried to replace the initWithAppId function with the [[FBSession] init] function, but it's crashing at [FBSession state]. I read on internet and I saw that if I have Facebook 5.0 app, but I don't have that application.

> ```
> fb_session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
> if(fb_session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
> { ... }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the two methods. Its up to you. For this, I will recommend you to follow  our Facebook for iOS SDK 3.0 Getting Started guide given here which has the step by step process to get you rolling.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-ios-sdk/

Comment: I followed all that steps. I downloaded a project from the internet(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLES2Sample/Introduction/Intro.html) and I succeeded to integrate the newest version of Facebook API. When I tried to integrate in my project, I had the above errors.